# Robocopying multiple folders at one time

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I have a folder per day in `c:/place/`, like `C:/place/2017-01-01` & `C:/place/2017-01-31`

I want to use robocopy to move `2017-01-0*` from `c:/place` to `d:/place`, what would be the proper syntax to move all of those folders at once?

I'm using PowerShell to accomplish the task, but I don't want to use a `do`/`FOR` as moving one folder at a time would take far too long.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a community not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (running `robocopy /?` might be a good start) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$source = "c:/place"
$dest= "d:/place"
robocopy   $source $dest /COPYALL /B /SEC /MIR
```